# Best way to save a CNN's weights in order to reuse them

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I would like to save weights (and biases) from a CNN that I implemented and trained from scratch using Tensorflow (Python API).

Now I would like to save these weights in a file and share it with someone so he can use my network. But since I have a lot of weights I don't know.  How can/should I do that?  Is there a format recommended to do that?

Comment: Tensorflow provides a way to save your model: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver. Your friend should then also use Tensorflow to load them.

Comment: Thank you ! Does it work if I want to use these parameters with the C++ API ?

Comment: Yes, there is no difference in the save formats of the same package with different language APIs.

Comment: Perfect then ! Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow provides a way to save your model: tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver. Your friend should then also use Tensorflow to load them. The language you load / save with doesn't affect how it is saved - if you save them in Tensorflow in Python they can be read in Tensorflow in C++.